# how i use the same legend for two different pie charts with apexcharts in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apexcharts

[Pie Charts to edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hte84.png)

I just need one LEGEND for these two charts, and that be reactive for both, how can I do??
I don't know if it is possible to connect the legend with any of the charts, programmatically way or something, with and "id" property or the same options for both charts...

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-card title="Apexchart">
      <b-card-body>
        <b-row>
          <b-col cols="6">
            <apexchart type="pie" :options="chartOptions" :series="series" />
          </b-col>
          <b-col cols="6"> 
            <apexchart type="pie" :options="chartOptions" :series="series" />
          </b-col>
        </b-row>
      </b-card-body>
    </b-card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Chart",
   data() {
    return {
      series: [60, 5, 10, 10],
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          width: "100%",
          type: "pie",
        },
        labels: ["legend-1", "legend-2", "legend-3", "legend-4"], //just need one, for both charts
        legend: {
          position: "bottom",
          offsetY: 0,
          markers: {
            radius: 4,
          }
        },
        title: {
          text: "Title",
          align: "center",
          offsetX: 0,
          offsetY: 0,
        },
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

PS: My English is awful, I know, but I try >:D

Comment: You can write series as well as a function ...series() {... I have done that.  Works. You could pass there a parameter, which alters the returned array in it. I have not done that.
Otherwise: Why not create a chart component, where you pass the desired series as props down to apexchart? Not that clean, but might be easier to maintain.

Comment: Or can't you just initiate two series? seriesA: [...], seriesB: [...]?